# Transpose rows and columns without aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have the following dataset

```
Date            Field1        Col1  Col2    Col3
2012/07/02      Customer1      CL   DS      RT
2012/07/03      Customer1      DS   RT      700
2012/07/04      Customer1      DS   RT      700
2012/07/02      Customer2      CL   DS      RT
2012/07/03      Customer2      DS   RT      1500
2012/07/04      Customer2      DS   RT      1500
2012/07/02      Customer3      CL   DS      RT
2012/07/03      Customer3      DS   RT      6000
2012/07/04      Customer3      DS   RT      6000
2012/07/02      Customer4      CL   RC      RT
2012/07/03      Customer4      RC   RT      4900
2012/07/04      Customer4      RC   RT      4900
```

I'd like output as follows:

```
Field1  2012/07/02  2012/07/03  2012/07/04
Col1    Customer1   CL  DS  DS
Col2    Customer1   DS  RT  RT
Col3    Customer1   RT  700 700
Col1    Customer2   CL  DS  DS
Col2    Customer2   DS  RT  RT
Col3    Customer2   RT  1500    1500
Col1    Customer3   CL  DS  DS
Col2    Customer3   DS  RT  RT
Col3    Customer3   RT  6000    6000
Col1    Customer4   CL  RC  RC
Col2    Customer4   RC  RT  RT
Col3    Customer4   RT  4900    4900
```

The problem is also that I have an unfixed amount of Customers (Field1) & unfixed amount of Dates.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is known as a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  There are two ways that these can be done, either with a static pivot where you hard-code all of the values to transform or a dynamic pivot where the values were determined at execution.

Static Version (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b93c/7)):

```
select *
from 
(
  select dt, field1, col, value
  from yourTable
  unpivot
  (
    value for col in (col1, col2, col3)
  ) u
)x1
pivot
(
  min(value)
  for dt in ([2012-07-02], [2012-07-03], [2012-07-04])
) p
```

Dynamic Pivot (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b93c/21)):

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourTable') and
               C.name like 'col%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), dt, 120))
                    from yourTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 
          'SELECT col, field1, ' + +@colsPivot+ '
           FROM
           (
              select dt, field1, col, value
              from yourTable
              unpivot
              (
                value for col in ('+ @colsUnpivot+')
              ) u
           )x1
           pivot
           (
             min(value)
             for dt in ('+@colsPivot+')
           ) p '

exec(@query)
```

The dynamic pivot is a great option when you do not know the number of items that you need to convert into columns. Both will yield the same results.

Edit #1, if you want the date columns in a specific order - desc, etc, then you will use the following to get the dates (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b93c/28)):

```
select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), dt, 120))
                    from yourTable
                    group by dt
                    ORDER by dt desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: I also need to order the Dates correctly. How do I do this in the Dynamic Version as it is apprearing incorrectly ordered at present with more data added?

Comment: @user1627440 please see my edit, you will alter the code slightly when getting the list of columns to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it without aggregates, but you do need to use Dynamic SQL to do it. Search for "SQL Dynamic Pivot" and you'll find plenty of posts about it. 
Like: [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

But better would be to do this in the client, as SQL's clients prefer to know what columns are being produced ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [SQL Server Pivot query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for your question.

You Can Use Below Query :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(date DATE, Field1 NVARCHAR(50), col1 NVARCHAR(30), col2 NVARCHAR(30),col3 NVARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO mytable(date,Field1,col1,col2,col3)
VALUES('2012/07/02','Customer1','CL','DS','RT')
...

SELECT Col, Field1, [2012/07/02],[2012/07/03],[2012/07/04]
FROM (SELECT Field1, 'Col1' AS Col, Date, Col1 AS ColVal
      FROM MyTable

      UNION ALL

      SELECT Field1, 'Col2' , Date, Col2 AS ColVal
      FROM MyTable

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT Field1, 'Col3' , Date, Col3 AS Col
      FROM MyTable
      )AS P
PIVOT (MIN(Colval) FOR Date IN ([2012/07/02],[2012/07/03],[2012/07/04])) AS Pvt
ORDER BY Field1, Col
```